# How to manage large java script data files?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing a Cordova project. to store my data I'm using java script files like this:

```
var groups = [
    {
        id: 1,
        parent_id: 0,
        name: "Group 1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 0,
        name: "Group 2"
    }
];
```

First problem is that I don't know if it is a good way or maybe there are better ways.
to use this data, simply I use a loop through variable, but the problem is when there are large data volumes, for example thousands of records. It's hard to handle this amount of data in a .js file. what should I do?

Comment: Possibly you can go for `lazy loading`, e.g. [rpnzl](http://rpnzl.com/code/lazyjson-v1.0/demo)

Comment: @Arvind What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a database such as IndexedDB(if your app is completely offline) or FireBase (if your app uses internet), you can query and get just the data you require.

Even DOM Storage (Local-Storage) is an option but there is the problem of looping over an array and this cannot store more than 5MB of data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is it possible to fill IndexedDB or FireBase on my pc and put the file in my app?

Comment: FireBase is a cloud based service which is platform independent you can add data to the DB from a PC and use it in your app. But for IndexedDB it cannot be done this way.

Comment: So it's not possible to fill IndexDB on PC? if not, what should I do?